# jQuery validate with rules and submitHandler, via AJAX issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple form, which I want to validate with validate() plugin. For some wierd reason, it's only working partially.
If both inputs are empty, the validation works, but if only one input has something in it, the validation doesn't work anymore and submits the form as it is.

Here the html

```
<form action="ajax/process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="newAccount3" class="validate">
                    <input type="hidden" name="postOp" value="account-creation-password">
                    <input type="password" id="usrPass" name="usrPass" class="form-control mt-3" required autofocus data-msg="Trebuie sa introduci o parola">
                    <input type="password" id="usrPassConfirm" name="usrPassConfirm" class="form-control mt-3" required data-msg="Parolele trebuie sa se potriveasca"><br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success alert-success px-5 px-sm-3 submitBtn">Continua</button>
                </form><hr>
```

And the JS

```
$('.validate').validate({
    ignore: ":hidden",
    rules: {
        usrPass: {
            required: true,
            minlenght: 6
        },
        usrPassConfirm: {
            required: true,
            minlenght: 6,
            equalTo: "#usrPass"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        var target = form.id;
        $.post('ajax/process.php',$('#'+target).serialize(),function(response){
            if(response.msg === 'OK-next'){
               location.reload();
            }
        },'json');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85KR4/466/)

Any ideeas ?

By the way, if I remove the rules from the jS, it's working, but I need the password to match.

There a [link](http://eligreen.ro/login)

to check it live, were it doesn't work. Just put a fake email address in, and in the next step you'll see the issue.

Comment: As a side note; I would also change `minLenght` to `minLength` to make that validation work :)

Comment: Well, you can play with the fiddle, I mean, no offense, but I've tried every thing I know, not being a newbie, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your Fiddle, it looks like you're loading jQuery 1.9.1 there. I've changed it to jQuery 3.2.1 and it all works.

```
$('.validate').validate({
    ignore: ":hidden",
    rules: {
        usrPass: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        usrPassConfirm: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo: "#usrPass"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        var target = form.id;           
        $.post('ajax/process.php',$('#'+target).serialize(),function(response){
            if(response.msg === 'OK-next'){
               location.reload();
            }
        },'json');
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85KR4/467/)

Comment: I really don't get it, I have jQuery 3.2.1 on my local machine, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it does, which only makes it even more wierd. I expected it to work the first time I wrote it, I've only created this post because it wasn't working.
Ohhh, I think I know what's the problem. My actual project load's the bootstrap.js as well, and I think there's a conflict.

Nope, I checked, that wasn't the issue.

Comment: It's not working on the server as well, here's the live address http://eligreen.ro
Enter a fake email address, and next form is the one that doesn't validate.